# Android - Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl returns null on first call

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I currently have a feature in my Android app that allows me to post a comment and attach a photo to it. The comment is uploaded to Cloud Firestore and the comment to Firebase Storage with a reference to the image through its download URL.

The problem I am having is that upon the first call to the method, it does not seem to retrieve the download URL, but when I make a second call it successfully retrieves it. Below I have included the method and this is simply called witin a button click listener.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_comments);

    submitComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            newComment();
        }
    });



        private void newComment() {

    Date date = new Date();
    EventComment mcomment = new EventComment();
    mcomment.setComment(commentText.getText().toString());
    mcomment.setDate_created(date);
   // mcomment.setUsername(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

    String commentID = Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));

    StorageReference filePath = firebaseStorage.child("Photos").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());

    filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            if(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() != null){
                imgDownloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

            } else if(taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl() != null) {
                imgDownloadUri = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    if (imgDownloadUri != null) {
        mcomment.setImageUri(imgDownloadUri.toString());

    }

    firestore.collection("events").document(event_id).collection("comments").document(commentID)
            .set(mcomment, SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Toast.makeText(EventCommentsActivity.this, "Comment posted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });


}

    firestore.collection("events").document(event_id).collection("comments").document(commentID)
            .set(mcomment, SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Toast.makeText(EventCommentsActivity.this, "Comment posted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

I have debugged this multiple times and I am unsure as to what is causing this. Perhaps it's to do the way the callbacks work and by having it all in one method may cause problems?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: you are using which version of `firebase` ?

Comment: @kdblue I'm using Firebase 11.4.2 and Firebase Storage 11.4.2 on an API 25 device

Comment: its happening because of callback !

Comment: @kdblue thanks for the response. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explain in code , see comment inside code , if you have any doubt then ask !

```
private void newComment() {
        StorageReference filePath = firebaseStorage.child("Photos").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
         //start progessbar here

        filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                if(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() != null){
                    imgDownloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                } else if(taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl() != null) {
                    imgDownloadUri = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
                }
                if (imgDownloadUri != null) {
                   //close progessbar here
            mcomment.setImageUri(imgDownloadUri.toString());

                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



        firestore.collection("events").document(event_id).collection("comments").document(commentID)
                .set(mcomment, SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(EventCommentsActivity.this, "Comment posted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I understand a bit better now. What would be a good way for me to restructure the code, so that it waits for the upload to complete and then gets the download URL?

Comment: `setImageUri` inside that `callback function`  and show progress bar if you want